# Any other + singular nouns

Tags: grammar

Can I use **any other** with a singular noun in the following context?

- Hey John, Trump has been awesome as the president of The Usa. I think he is absolutely going to win the next election for president. Is there **any other candidate** suitable for being president?

I know people would say I should say 'Are there **any other people**...?'. But when I use plural nouns I am expecting a yes answer. The answerer can say there are many. But I am here expecting a 'no answer. I am not in a position to hear a 'yes answer'. If the answerer said 'yes', I would be very surprised.

Comment: What do you mean that you expect a yes or no answer depending on whether you use a singular or plural pronoun?

Comment: Some people say when you use 'any' with singular nouns, it expresses boubt. I am not sure. So I want to get confirmed.

Comment: You could say "is there anyone?" Or "are there any people/candidates?" and imply doubt in the same way using singular or plural nouns.

Comment: Thank you. So can I say 'Is there any other candidate suitable for being president?'?

Comment: Yep! Absolutely.